# Complex regex extraction in node/io

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, io.js

There is the library Twitter Text that I try to use.
It has a tons of complex regexps that are calculated in runtime. I don't need all the library so I decided to just use some regexp from it.

So I have a script to extract it and save to another js file:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var fs = require('fs');
var twitterText = require('twitter-text');   // 1.11.0 (latest)

var content = [
    '/**',
    ' * @preserve https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js',
    ' */',
    'var regexps = { };'
];

_.forEach({
    url: 'extractUrl',         // <- this regexp is the problem
    hash: 'validHashtag',
    mention: 'validMentionOrList'
}, function(twitterTextRegexpName, regexpName) {
    var regexp = twitterText.regexen[twitterTextRegexpName];

    if (undefined === regexp) {
        throw new Error('Failed to find regexp ' + twitterTextRegexpName);
    }

    content.push(
        'regexps.' + regexpName + ' = ' + regexp + ';'
    );
} );

content.push('export default regexps;');

fs.writeFile(targetPath, content.join('\n'), {}, callback);
```

So the result screenshot:

[image: result]

As you can see the url regexp is broken and I can't use module.

```
> require('./result');
.../result.js:5
regexps.url = /(((?:[^A-Za-z0-9@＠$#＃‪-‮]|^))((https?:\/\/)?((?:(?:(?:[^\/\!
              ^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:393:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:428:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:335:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:345:17)
    at require (module.js:364:17)
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:124:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
```

Any thoughts? Tried with latest node and io.

Comment: Maybe you want to try it with `'regexps.' + regexpName + ' = ' + regexp.source + ';`

Comment: It seems to be pretty hard :) Here is an excellent reference about unicode which explains a lot: [https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode).

Comment: I believe that my script generates a valid regexp. I've successfully tested it with some test cases from original twitter-text package, tomorrow I'll check all remaining ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script seems to work (it uses [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-string-escape)):

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var fs = require('fs');
var twitterText = require('twitter-text');   // 1.11.0 (latest)
jsStringEscape = require('js-string-escape');

var content = [
    '/**',
    ' * @preserve https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js',
    ' */',
    'var regexps = { };'
];

_.forEach({
    url: 'extractUrl',         // <- this regexp is the problem
    hash: 'validHashtag',
    mention: 'validMentionOrList'
}, function(twitterTextRegexpName, regexpName) {
    var regexp = twitterText.regexen[twitterTextRegexpName];

    if (undefined === regexp) {
        throw new Error('Failed to find regexp ' + twitterTextRegexpName);
    }

    var regexpStr = jsStringEscape(regexp.toString());
    var regexpRegexp  = /\/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/;  // :)
    var result = regexpStr.match(regexpRegexp);
    var regexpBody      = result[1];
    var regexpModifiers = result[2];
    content.push(
        'regexps.' + regexpName + ' = new RegExp("' + regexpBody + '","' + regexpModifiers + '");'
    );
} );

content.push('module.exports = regexps;');
fs.writeFile("./out.js", content.join('\n'), {});
```

Output:

```
node

> var r = require("./out.js");
undefined
> "www.google.com".match(r.url)
[ 'www.google.com' ]
> "something".match(r.url)
null
```

The resulting regexp for urls passes these tests from the original package:

**[Test for invalid characters in url](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/js/test/tests.js#L241) (The result should be null):**

```
var r = require("./out.js");
var invalidChars = ['\u202A', '\u202B', '\u202C', '\u202D', '\u202E'];
for (var i = 0; i < invalidChars.length; i++) {
    console.log(("http://twitt" + invalidChars[i] + "er.com").match(r.url));
}

// Result:
// null
// null
// null
// null
// null
```

**[Extract url test](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/js/test/tests.js#L304)**

```
> var r = require("./out.js");
> var message_with_hyphenated_url = "Message with hyphenated-url.com";
undefined
> var message_with_www_hyphenated_url = "Message with www.123-hyphenated-url.com";
undefined
> message_with_hyphenated_url.match(r.url)
[ ' hyphenated-url.com' ]
> message_with_www_hyphenated_url.match(r.url)
[ ' www.123-hyphenated-url.com' ]
// Load original regex:
> var twitterText = require('twitter-text');
undefined
> var rr = twitterText.regexen["extractUrl"];
undefined
> message_with_hyphenated_url.match(rr)
[ ' hyphenated-url.com' ]
> message_with_www_hyphenated_url.match(rr)
[ ' www.123-hyphenated-url.com' ]
// The same results as with original regex.
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but for it did not work for me. (node 0.12.1) Btw. what is your system? (mine MacOS 10.9.5)

Comment: Sorry, I experimented with my answer a bit and at some point the last line went missing (`fs.writeFile("./out.js", content.join('\n'), {});`), so that the output that once was valid was not updated at all. :) I've reverted my answer to a correct one.

Could You please check if it works for You?

Comment: Not only the last line was missing previously but this part `require('js-string-escape');` as well ;) Anyway `.url` is still different than what have been pushed to `content`. In your file it starts with '- //' whereas in the original with '((('.

Comment: The `require('js-string-escape');` was removed intentionally, as I was trying to get rid of an extra dependency...

Comment: When you refer to "original file", You mean `twitter-text.js`? It shouldn't be expected that my output will match exactly the definition from `twitter-text.js` since some kind of Regex builder (`regexSupplant`) is used there.

Comment: Kind of - I meant the regexp obtained from: `var regexp = twitterText.regexen[twitterTextRegexpName];` Compare this and yours and you will see they are different.

Comment: But take a look at `twitterText.regexen["extractUrl"].source`. The beginning of the string is the same as in my file.

Comment: Nice work, thank you. Generated and original sources are equal https://gist.github.com/silentroach/b33e7efd844d8ec97edf